# Mocking a smart card response using pyscard

Tags: python, mifare, pyscard

I'm trying to mock a response in a small function using some pyscard attributes.

My function:

```py
def card_reader():
    # request any card type
    cardtype = AnyCardType()
    cardrequest = CardRequest(timeout=25, cardType=cardtype)
    cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()

    # attach the console tracer
    observer = ConsoleCardConnectionObserver()
    cardservice.connection.addObserver(observer)

    # connect to the card and perform a few transmits
    cardservice.connection.connect()

    try:
        response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit(ADPU)

    except SWException as e:
        print(str(e))

    cardservice.connection.disconnect()
```

And my mock:

```py
@patch("my_module.temp_card_reader.CardRequest")
def test_card_reader(mock_card_request):
    mock_card_request.return_value.connection.transmit.return_value = (200, 201, 203)
    result = card_reader()
```

Using my test, I can mock until `cardservice.connection.connect()`, but I can't go forward to return a value that I want.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error? I'm thinking that your mocked `.transmit` returns a single value (`"my value"`) whereas the actual code seems to be returning a tuple with three elements. Can you do `print(response, sw1, sw2)` in the _actual_ `card_reader` function (right after `.transmit(ADPU)`) and see what those values are?

Comment: Hello. When I put a tuple in `return_vale`, the mock returns this value: `<MagicMock name='CardRequest().waitforcard().connection.transmit()' id='140012280376160'>` ( I put only variable to test this).

And I got this error (in test): `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)`

Comment: I'm a bit flying blind here and I doubt I can be of much help. But I THINK you're seeing that as a "MagicMock" and not as your string or your tuple because you mocked `cardrequest`. Then the mock runs `cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()` and it doesn't know what `.waitforcard()` should return ,and therefore it returns a MagicMock. I **think** this is the behavior of the mocks (think... not sure...) I _suspect_ that you might also need to mock a `cardservice`... somehow. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: You helped a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was curious myself  Glad I helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always been intrigued by Mocks, MagicMocks and my apparent lack of knowledge about them , that's why I was curious about this.

I could totally be wrong, but I think what is happening is the following:

1. The mocked class is `CardRequest`.
2. At a certain point, there's this `cardservice = cardrequest.waitforcard()`
3. Because nothing (no side-effect, no return_value... ) for `.waitforcard()` is defined, the MagicMock() says *"Oh... ok... I guess I'll return a blank (default?) MagicMock here"* (meaning: `cardservice` is a default MagicMock)
4. And when you try to call an unspecified method on a MagicMock, it will keep returning MagicMocks.

I **think** (I've tested but I'm not super-confident, since I'm missing the actual code) that the solution is to tell the `CardRequest` mock something along the lines of: *"Hey, when they call `.waitforcard()`, don't return a blank (default?) MagicMock, but rather **THIS** `mock_cardservice` mock which knows how to handle the `.transmit` method"*

So maaaybe mocking a `cardservice` would work:

```
@patch("my_module.temp_card_reader.CardRequest")
def test_card_reader(mock_card_request):
    mock_cardservice = MagicMock()
    mock_cardservice.connection.transmit.return_value = (200, 201, 203)
    mock_card_request.return_value.waitforcard.return_value = mock_cardservice
    result = card_reader()
```

With this, I've been able to see `200 201 203` if I do a print right after `cardservice.connection.transmit(ADPU)`:

```
    response, sw1, sw2 = cardservice.connection.transmit(ADPU)
    print(response, sw1, sw2)
```